# JavaScript Othello left and right convert functions

Tags: javascript

```js
var cW = 800;
var cH = 800;
var board = [];
var numturn = 0;
var turn = "black"
var s = cW/8;

function setup()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var WindowRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var output2 = document.getElementById("output2");
    var output3 = document.getElementById("output3");
    
    drawBoard(ctx);
    drawChip(ctx, "black", 3, 3);
    drawChip(ctx, "white", 3, 4);
    drawChip(ctx, "white", 4, 3);
    drawChip(ctx, "black", 4, 4);
        
    for (var c = 0; c < 8; c++)
    {
        board.push(["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""])
    };
    
    board[3][3] = "black";
    board[3][4] = "white";
    board[4][3] = "white";
    board[4][4] = "black";
    
    function clicked(evt)
    {
        var c = getCol(evt.clientX-WindowRect.left);
        var r = getRow(evt.clientY-WindowRect.top);
    
        if (!boardFull()) 
        {
            if (validMove(r, c))
            {    
                drawChip(ctx, turn, r, c);
                
                convertLeft(ctx, r, c, turn);
                convertRight(ctx, r, c, turn);
                convertUp(ctx, r, c, turn);
                convertDown(ctx, r, c, turn);
                console.log("Piece at " + "row:" + r + " col:" + c + " " + board[r][c]);
                
                board[r][c] = turn;
                
                if (turn === "white")
                {
                    turn = "black";
                }
                else
                {
                    turn = "white";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            winner = checkWin();
            output.innerHTML = winner + " wins";
        }
        
        console.log("Row: " + r)
        console.log("Col: " + c)
        console.log("")
        console.log(board[0]);
        console.log(board[1]);
        console.log(board[2]);
        console.log(board[3]);
        console.log(board[4]);
        console.log(board[5]);
        console.log(board[6]);
        console.log(board[7]);
        console.log("");
    }
    
    canvas.addEventListener('click', clicked);  
};

function drawBoard(ctx)
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, cW, cH);
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
      
    for(var c = 0; c < 8; c++)
    {
        var x = c * s;
        for (var r = 0; r < 8; r++)
        {
            var y = r * s + (s/2);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(x, 800);
            ctx.moveTo(0, x);
            ctx.lineTo(800, x);
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.lineWidth = 2.5;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
};

function drawChip(ctx, color, r, c)
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    var x = c * s + (s/2);
    var y = r * s + (s/2);
    ctx.arc(x, y, cW/(s/5), 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
};

function getRow(x)
{
    return Math.floor(x/s);
};

function getCol(y)
{
    return Math.floor(y/s);
};

function validMove(r, c)
{
    return board[r][c] === "";
};

function convertLeft(ctx, r, c, color)
{
    for (var left = (c - 1); left > -1; left--)
    {
        if (board[r][left] == board[r][c])
        {
            for (var Lins = c; Lins > left; Lins--)
            {
                drawChip(ctx, color, r, Lins);
                board[r][Lins] = color;
            }
        }
    }
};

function convertRight(ctx, r, c, color)
{
    for (var right = (c + 1); right < 8; right++)
    {
        if (board[r][right] == board[r][c])
        {
            for (var Rins = c; Rins < right; Rins++)
            {
                drawChip(ctx, color, r, Rins);
                board[r][Rins] = color;
            }
        }
    }
};

function convertUp(ctx, r, c, color)
{
    for (var up = (r - 1); up > -1; up--)
    {
        if (board[up][c] == board[r][c])
        {
            for (var Uins = r; Uins > up; Uins--)
            {
                drawChip(ctx, color, Uins, c);
                board[Uins][c] = color;
            }
        }
    }
};

function convertDown(ctx, r, c, color)
{
    for (var down = (r + 1); down < 8; down++)
    {
        if (board[down][c] == board[r][c])
        {
            for (var Dins = r; Dins < down; Dins++)
            {
                drawChip(ctx, color, Dins, c);
                board[Dins][c] = color;
            }
        }
    }
};

function validSpot(ctx, r, c)
{
    
};

function checkWin()
{
    var black = 0;
    var white = 0;
    for (var r = 0; r < board.length; r++)
    {
        for (var c = 0; c< board[0].length; c++)
        {
            if (board[r][c] == "black")
            {
                black++;
            }
            if (board[r][c] == "white")
            {
                white++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    output2.innerHTML = "black pieces: " + black;
    output3.innerHTML = "white pieces: " + white;
    
    if (white > black)
    {
        return "white"
    }
    if (white < black)
    {
        return "black"
    }
    else
    {
        return "no one"
    }  
};

function boardFull()
{
    for (var r = 0; r < board.length; r++)
    {
        for (var c = 0; c< board[0].length; c++)
        {
            if (board[r][c] === "")
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
    }
    return true;
};
```

When the program runs, the convertLeft and converRight functions don't seem to properly convert the pieces according to the color, but the convertUp and convertDown functions do. What might be the problem for this bit of code?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Othello</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Othello.js"></script>
    
    <style type="text/css">
      canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
    </style>
    
  </head>
  <body onload="setup();";>
    <h1>Virtual Othello</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
    <br>
    <h1 id="output">
    <h1 id="output2">
    <h1 id="output3">
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the HTML I used to run the JavaScript on Chrome. I also used Komodo IDE. Just correspond the file names to link them to each other